# Why does bundler keep installing gems I already have?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, bundler

I have updated my system to Mountain Lion, built a new version of Ruby and, as far as I know, reinstalled all my old gems. However, whenever I cd into an old app and run the bundle command it takes an age because it is re-installing gems I know that I have on my system:

```
Using rake (0.9.2.2) 
Using i18n (0.6.0) 
Using multi_json (1.0.4) 
Installing activesupport (3.2.1) 
Using builder (3.0.0) 
Installing activemodel (3.2.1) 
Using erubis (2.7.0) 
Installing journey (1.0.1) 
Using rack (1.4.1) 
Using rack-cache (1.1) 
Using rack-test (0.6.1) 
Using hike (1.2.1) 
Using tilt (1.3.3) 
Installing sprockets (2.1.2) 
Installing actionpack (3.2.1) 
Using mime-types (1.17.2) 
Using polyglot (0.3.3) 
Using treetop (1.4.10) 
Installing mail (2.4.1) 
Installing actionmailer (3.2.1) 
Installing arel (3.0.0) 
Using tzinfo (0.3.31)
```

Any thoughts, suggestions or ideas of what to look for would be really appreciated.

Comment: Is it possible the versions of ruby are different in each context? That would explain it.

Answer (score 1):

My first answer, but I would suggest using RVM to manage ruby versions and gemsets.
Check out [RVM](https://rvm.io/)

After that, just create a .rvmrc file that you can find examples online.  The power of the .rvmrc is that it runs whenever you "cd" into an app with that file present.  So it will set your RVM with the appropriate Ruby Version and the appropriate Gemset (with all your gems)  and never have to worry about versions and gems being conflicted or overlapped or not there etc...

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I am actually using RVM at the moment.

Comment: Ok, since  you are already using RVM and you're developing a Rails App I believe... And let's assume you're using Bundler to manager your gem dependencies, I would suggest locking down your versions in your Gemfile.  Basically give it specific versions for each gem.  
This way, when your bundler runs, it takes the specific version and also stores a local cache version in your vendor/cache directory.  That way, when deploying anywhere, you can do bundle install local.